# Will publish profile work for setting EnvironmentName if not publishing to IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, publish

I use this same method to set the eonvironmentname for a web app that I publish to a folder.  However, when publishing a .net core console app that is using IWebhostBuilder, the environmentname isnt seeming to get updated?

I have a .net core console app that I am publishing to a folder location and the console app uses IWebhostBuilder, hence I need to be able to set the environment name prior to publishing.  It seems to want to grab the default appsettings, rather than the one for my target environment (Dev).  I have a appsettings.Dev.json file

[image]

My publish profile looks like this

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Dev</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>\\dev-server1\d$\Services\BoxService</PublishDir>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <EnvironmentName>Dev</EnvironmentName>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**[ Edit ]**
Nothing was working, so I did an experiment because obviously I am missing something or just dont understand.  I created a new test console app with nothing in it except one class with a Main method.  Added the necessary packages (Extensions.Configuration etc), then proceeded to publish the app to a local folder with the following in my publishprofile.

```
<EnvironmentName>Local</EnvironmentName>
```

This is obviously not being used, because when I run it from visual studio, it reports the correct environment has been set, but when run from the published folder, its as if the environment has not been set.

```
Here is Program.cs 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Cmd1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


            var environmentName =
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT");

            // create service collection
            var services = new ServiceCollection();


            // build config
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            // setup config
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("App"));

            // create service provider
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var appSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();

            string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment");

            Console.WriteLine($" We are looking at {appSettings.Value.TempDirectory} from environment: {env}");
        }
    }
}
```

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "App": {
    "TempDirectory": "d:\temp"
  }
}
```

Appsettings.Local.json

```
{
  "App": {
    "TempDirectory": "c:\\temp\\rss-hero\\tmp\\"
  }
}
```

Setting Environment in VS
[image]

Results, from VS

[image]

Results when run from published folder
[image]

Comment: After the publish open Powershell in publish dir. Run `$Env:ENVIRONMENT = "Development"` and then start the application using `dotnet .\appName.dll`. Your application will use the specified env you specified earlier in the command.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure `IWebhostBuilder` like this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Dev.json", optional: true) // add more if you have
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    });
```

Then depending on the environment it will use `appsettings{envrionment}.json`. If no other present it will use `appsettings.json` (default). After publishing you can check the `web.config` to check the environment name it's using.

**EDIT**

For console app you do something like this

```
private static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, string environmentName)
    {
        return config
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
```

And use like this (.Net core generic host)

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
{
    Configure(builder, "Dev");
})
.UseConsoleLifetime()
```

Or if you want to get the environment from System environment variables.

```
public static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var env = new HostingEnvironment
        {
            EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"),
            ApplicationName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
            ContentRootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            ContentRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        };

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var configured = Configure(config, env);
        return configured.Build();
    }
```

Comment: But I am not building a web app.  This is for a console app.  Im building a windows service. Hence, there will be no web.config

Comment: Then you can use `EnvironmentName` like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#environmentname). And you should switch to generic host.

Comment: Yes, I am doing those things, but still wasnt working (although Im using webhostbuilder).  See update in orginal post